# convert a <select> under angular2

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-template, angular-template

I'm switching to angular2+ right now. And I'm a little stuck on this line, I don't find the right writing:

Here is the old version (1.6):

```
    <select ng-model="selectedPet" ng-options="pet.id as pet.pseudo for pet in pets" required></select>
```

And here is the new version(2+):

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedPet">
<option *ngFor="let pet.id as pet.pseudo for pet in pets" required></option>
```

I can't find the solution for the *ngFor.

I apologize for my English and thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedPet">
    <option [value]="pet.id" *ngFor="let pet of pets">{{pet.pseudo}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedPet" required>
  <option *ngFor="let pet of pets" [value]='pet' ></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but it doesn't give me exactly the desired result.